# How do I make OS X set the terminal title back to the original title when coming back from ssh?

Tags: macos, bash, ssh, shell, terminal.app

Starting on OS X, I ssh into foo (a Linux box).  My terminal title changes to foo.  I then ssh into bar (another Linux box).  My terminal title changes to bar.  I log out of bar.  My terminal title changes to foo.  I log out of foo.  My terminal title stays foo (rather than changing back to the original title).  The problem is obviously not with the terminal, since it works correctly when logging out of a Linux box back to a Linux box.  It probably isn't ssh as I have the same problem with vim.  In my mind that leaves the shell.  I am using BASH.  Looking through the environment I don't see a lot of difference between the Linux box and my OS X box.  Both are using a TERM of xterm.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Adding

```
export PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\033]0;${USER}@${HOSTNAME}: ${PWD/$HOME/~}\007"'
```

to my `.bash_profile` fixed the problem.

It appears as if the string in `PROMPT_COMMAND` gets executed every time the prompt is displayed.  From the man page:

> PROMPT_COMMAND
>
> If set, the value is executed as a command prior to issuing each primary prompt.

Comment: You're unlikely to log into OS X via the console, but it might happen. To prevent problems in that event, I wrap this whole thing in a `case "$TERM" in xterm*|rxvt*)` type of deal. I think I originally got the idea from here: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/xterm-title-bar-manipulations.html

Comment: Oh, also, I find it better to go into Terminal.app's preferences (Preferences -> Settings -> Window) and remove everything that it tries to add to the title-bar, but ymmv.

Comment: Well, I use `iTerm.app` not `Terminal.app`, and it is working.  You do have a point about the real terminal.  My Linux box has just such a check, so I will add it to my profile, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I've found better solution for this issue. OSX uses this system wide configuration:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND="update_terminal_cwd${PROMPT_COMMAND:+; $PROMPT_COMMAND}"
```

Function `update_terminal_cmd` is declared in `/etc/bashrc_Apple_Terminal`. Therefore, if you do not want to break your Terminal settings by resetting `PROMPT_COMMAND`, you can add these lines  to the end of your `~/.profile` or `~/.bashrc`:

```
my_update_terminal_cwd() {
    update_terminal_cwd # call system wide function
    printf '\e]0;\a'    # reset additional title after SSH session
}

PROMPT_COMMAND="my_update_terminal_cwd${PROMPT_COMMAND:+; $PROMPT_COMMAND}"
```

Example:

[Before SSH session](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q3doR.png)

[SSH session in progress - title set to remote hostname](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDI9q.png)

[After SSH session - title fixed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EmKTh.png)