# Change Terminal Title in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, bash

How can I arbitrarily change the title of a Terminal window in Mac OS X? I have seen [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/28931/how-do-i-make-os-x-set-the-terminal-title-back-to-the-original-title-when-coming) and [this magicwrap thing](http://purpleamy.com/magicwrap/), but think it's just a simple Mac OS X command.

Comment: Should note that there's nothing OS X specific about this -- the answer will work on pretty much any terminal.

Comment: Is it Bash-specific then?

Comment: @Andrew Aylett, so the script I put in my answer (below) will work on the linux distros, too?

Comment: Yes, it should work anywhere (with an sh-derived shell) that uses unix-y terminals.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

This [article](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/705/mac-os-x-change-the-terminal-window-title/) tells you how.

Essentially, you use character sequences echoed to the screen to inform the terminal of what title it should display.

```
title='My first title'
echo -n -e "\033]0;$title\007"
```

In the above example, whatever the variable title is set to while become the terminal's title. Of course, you could just have the title in the string to echo such as:

```
echo -n -e "\033]0;My first title\007"
```

But the first way makes it a slightly bit easier to use and/or extend later.

Comment: Excellent. Could you include a sample script (like this? `echo -n -e "\033]0;$1\007"`) in your answer so I can mark it best answer, please?

Comment: *printf* may be more reliable: `printf "\033]0;%s\007" "$title_variable"` (the various options and behaviors of *echo* are not the same across all systems, shells, or even shell options) Also, variable assignments in *bash* should not have spaces around the equals sign.

Comment: I used $* and within a function, so I wouldn't have to quote my title string.

Comment: Is there a way to change the title from within a C program? The program I'm thinking about is running animation based on ncurses.h so I am not sure how to echo to the terminal :-(

Comment: OK: Just fprintf(stdout,..) works. I should have tried before asking.

Comment: what about tab name

Answer (score 38):

Adding the following to your `~/.profile` will achieve the same effect:

```
# function for setting terminal titles in OSX
function title {
  printf "\033]0;%s\007" "$1"
}
```

And then a quick `title 'et voila'` will sort all your tabs out.

Comment: why is it a problem if you have many functions in .profile? is there a limit?

Comment: IDK why, but had to edit .bash_profile instead of .profile

Comment: Or: `alias title="printf '\033]0;%s\007'"`.

Comment: `export alias title="printf '\033]0;%s\007'"`

Comment: You can also add it using `sudo nano /etc/bashrc`. This should run for all the users. Restart terminal session or do `source /etc/bashrc` to apply your changes.

Comment: this changes the "Terminal Title" but not the Tab Title.

Comment: To add to this great suggestion, I opted to use the variable `$*` instead of `$1`, so that the title function can be used without having to quote the argument, e.g. `title hello world this is my tab title`

Answer (score 8):

Remix of Dan MgG's answer:

```
echo -n -e "\033]0;$1\007"
```

Store it in a file called /usr/bin/title (using sudo!) and chmod it to +x. Then from anywhere you can just type

```
title 'Trying to Figure This GIT Thing Out'
```

and you get a nice little title.

(Syntax may vary if you're not on OSX, if I understand correctly)

Comment: If you're on one of those newer versions of OS X you may to do `/usr/local/bin/title` instead.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to sh-based command line solutions, the OS X Terminal app has a preference to change the title as follows: Under the Terminal->shell menu there is a "edit title" choice, select that and you can change the title easily.

Answer (score 2):

The reply marked as Best answer works fine... this is what i did...

```
tell application "Terminal"
    activate
    do script "echo -n -e \"\\033]0;WorkerTab1\\007\"; cd $HOME/folder1"
end tell
```

this will set the name of the new tab to WorkerTab1 and then perform other commands like "cd" , etc.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for this. I just added a function to my .bashrc:

```
    function stit() {
    echo -n -e "\033]0;$1\007"
}
```

In my mind "stit" = a convenient shortcut for "set_title". And now when I want to set the title of my windows on the fly, I type:

```
stit "[new window title]"
```

Answer (score 1):

On OS X, terminal preferences are stored in `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Terminal.plist`.

The terminal's title is stored in the `WindowTitle` preference.